# Second event added not being registered/called, when EventHandler<T> stored in a dictionary

Tags: c#, events, delegates

**EDIT: Rewriting because I poorly explained the original problem.**

### Problem: Classes subscribing to another class's events, which are referenced in a dictionary, are not called when the event fires.  When all code is inside the class that contains the events, everything works fine.

I'm using a dictionary to allow me to handle events/handlers based on an enum (EventType):

```
Dictionary<EventType, EventHandler<EventArgs>> eventLookup;
```

In order to populate this dictionary, I reflect through a class containing a large amount of events and assign a new empty EventHandler to each event. Then I associate an EventType value with each EventHandler:

```
public void EngineEvents::Initialize()
{
    foreach (EventInfo eventInfo in this.GetType().GetEvents())
    {
        eventInfo.GetAddMethod(true).Invoke(this, new[] { new EventHandler<EventArgs>(this.UselessHandler) });
    }

    this.eventLookup = new Dictionary<EventType, EventHandler<EventArgs>>
    {
        { EventType.Initialize, this.OnInitialize },
    };
}

 private void UselessHandler(object sender, EventArgs args) { }
 public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnInitialize;
```

Other code can subscribe to OnInitialize and should receive the event.

```
 engineEvents.OnInitialize += this.OnInitialize;
```

When an event is fired I index into the dictionary, and invoke the multicast delegate:

```
public void EngineEvents::FireEvent(EventType eventType)
{
    if (this.eventLookup.ContainsKey(eventType))
    {
        this.eventLookup[eventType](this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

This works beautifully for anything done inside EngineEvents, the class that contains the events and the lookup dictionary.

When I subscribe to EngineEvents' event from:

```
public class CallingClass
{
    public CallingClass(EngineEvents engine)
    {
        engine.OnInitialize += this.OnInitialize;
    }

    private void OnInitialize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("calling class's method called");
    }
}
```

This OnInitialize is never called, but UselessHandler in EngineEvents is.

How other code triggers this event:

```
engineEvents.FireEvent(EventType.Initialize);
```

To summarize:
Only EngineEvents' EventHandlers stay relevant, and external subscribers to the event are not called.

Complete sample, for Console application.  Breakpoints on CallingClass's OnInitialize, and EngineEvents's UselessHandler shows that one is called and not the other.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Reflection;

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EngineEvents engine = new EngineEvents();
            engine.Initialize();

            CallingClass calling = new CallingClass(engine);

            engine.FireEvent(EventType.Initialize);
        }
    }

    public class EngineEvents
    {
        private Dictionary<EventType, EventHandler<EventArgs>> eventLookup;

        public void Initialize()
        {
            foreach (EventInfo eventInfo in this.GetType().GetEvents())
            {
                eventInfo.GetAddMethod(true).Invoke(this, new[] { new EventHandler<EventArgs>(this.UselessHandler) });
            }

            this.eventLookup = new Dictionary<EventType, EventHandler<EventArgs>>
            {
                { EventType.Initialize, this.OnInitialize },
            };
        }

        private void UselessHandler(object sender, EventArgs args) { }

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnInitialize;

        public void FireEvent(EventType eventType)
        {
            if (this.eventLookup.ContainsKey(eventType))
            {
                this.eventLookup[eventType](this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
    public enum EventType
    {
        Initialize,
    }

    public class CallingClass
    {
        public CallingClass(EngineEvents engine)
        {
            engine.OnInitialize += this.OnInitialize;
        }

        private void OnInitialize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("calling class's method called");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this solves a maintenance nightmare?

Comment: You subscribe the Useless handler to the events but store the other handlers as delegates in an unrelated dictionary. The FireEvent should use the dictionary, a normal action should trigger the Useless one.

Comment: Unclear how you will handle duplicate keys and what you hope to achieve here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, sorry are you making a suggestion or telling me what I'm doing wrong?  There is only one dictionary being used, I can confirm that.

Also, a delegate can have multiple targets, so I'm avoiding duplicate keys, by utilizing the ability to do an add on an event several times.

I feel that one register loop, one unregister loop and a lookup dictionary is better than a lot of normal event handling code one sees where every event is handled as a line or two for each interaction.

Comment: I'm mainly telling you that the question is hard to follow. There still is no connection between any event and the dictionary afaict.  Boil it down to a small but complete example.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully the rewrite makes more sense.

Comment: (I'll never figure out how the mini-Markdown's code formatting works.)

Should be noted that when I internalize the event's add to EngineEvent, it works fine:

`public void AttachEvent(EngineEventType eventType,` `EventHandler<EngineEventArgs> handler)`
 `{   this.eventLookup[eventType] += handler;  }`

`this.EngineEvents.AttachEvent(EngineEventType.Initialize,`
`this.BeforeValidation);`

Comment: Don't add so much code in comments, see how it looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I got it.

First, you cannot "store events in a Dictionary"  or in anything else. An `event` is (a kind of) a property and cannot be stored by reference. Your dictionary stores the content of those properties, delegates.

What happens is:

1. You subscribe UselessHandler through reflection
2. You fill the dictionary with the initializer `{ EventType.Initialize, this.OnInitialize },`
3. You subscribe another handler from the calling class with `+=`
4. You raise an 'event' through the dictionary.

The problem is that at step 2) you *think* that you are capturing an event. But you are only reading the event and storing the delegate value at that moment (containing only the Useless handler)

In step 3) you subscribe to the actual event, nothing inside the dictionary changes

In step 4) only the delegate in the dictionary is invoked, not the updated delegate in the event.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that I was confusing terms, the event/eventhandler (delegate) relationship is one I always trip over when describing.

What you describe certainly explains what I'm seeing.

If I bring this all into the EngineEvents class, it works fine, is there some reason why the same calls internally work, but externally don't?

Also, I thought delegates stored as references?  Why am I only getting a snapshot of it at that time?  Is there a way around that?

Comment: You would have to add a public SubScribe method (and publish the `EventType`s). By then you are completely circumventing the `event`s with your own callback system.

Comment: Or reimplement the add/remove parts of all the events.

Comment: Cool, both those are something I tried and they worked.  So what was getting me was that I was storing a delegate at that time, and it doesn't update like I expected with future targets.

Thanks!